# Renaming an uploaded file

Tags: php

after uploading a file, I want to rename it by appending today's date to the end.

Here is an example of putting today's date at the *beginning* of the file:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], "docs/".$upload_date.$_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
```

But if I try to add it to the end, it gets added AFTER the file's extension
for example "testdoc.pdf2014-05-29"

but I want:
"testdoc 2014-05-29.pdf"

How do I insert today's date (or any variable) *in between* the filename and the extension?

Comment: i dont believe there is a way

Comment: what do you think you should do? it seems trivial...

Comment: Use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) to parse the file name.  Then reassemble it in the way you want.

Comment: @Mr.coder: I hope you're being sarcastic :-P

Comment: If you don't think there is a way you probably should not use the name Mr coder LOL

Comment: I remember the (first) time I wanted to do this and I Google'd it. Took me what.... 5 minutes, *not even.*

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
//split file name with "."
$fileName = explode(".", $_FILES['imagefile']['name']);

//remove extension from file name and save it in variable
$extension = array_pop($fileName);

//join back the array without extension
$fileName = implode(".", $fileName);

//get new file name by appending upload date and extension
$newFileName = $fileName . ' ' . $upload_date . '.' . $extension;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], "docs/".$newFileName);
```

You could achieve same thing by using `pathinfo` read up on it and try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pathParts = pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
$fileNameExtension = $pathParts['extension'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], "docs/" . $pathParts['filename'] . ' ' . $upload_date . '.' . $fileNameExtension);
```

Comment: I'd assume you really meant `"docs/" . $path_parts['filename'] . ' ' . $upload_date . '.' . $fileNameExtension`?